# Rails add quantity to cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question:

`@order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by(product_id: params[:product_id])`

I want to add one to the order item’s quantity before the `.save` is called.

The default value of the `quantity` is `0`. Here is my complete code:

```
def create
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find_or_initialize_by(product_id: params[:product_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Successfully added product to cart.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Im new to ruby and rails. How to do that?  Thank you

**UPDATE**

```
<tr>
    <th>Items:</th>
    <td><%= @order.order_items.count %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <% @order.order_items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= image_tag "products/#{item.product.image_url}" %></td>
        <td><%= item.product.title %></td>
        <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
        <td><%= print_price item.product.price %></td>
        <td><%= print_price item.subtotal %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Remove', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
    <th>TOTAL</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><%= print_price @order.total %></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
```

My current code is only print out total `order_items` in some `order`, what if for example each `order_item` quantity is `2`. So I want to print out all total quantity.

```
<%= @order.order_items.count %>
```

How to do that?

Comment: you have a orders table with an attribute of quantity correct?

Comment: @Cyzanfar correct sir

Comment: have you tried `@order_item.increment!(:quantity)`?

Comment: @Cyzanfar nah .. now this works. but what if I have to update current items quantity in one order? `@order.order_items.count` only count the order item not the quantity

Comment: `@order.order_items.quantity`? not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have quantity attribute in order_items table, you can do that by simply assigning value to the setter, before saving.

```
@order_item.quantity = 1
```

**Update:**
I assume, you want order items quantities sum. 
You can find total order_items quantities by

```
@order.order_items.sum(:quantity)
```

Replace your

```
<th>Items:</th>
<td><%= @order.order_items.count %></td>
```

with

```
<th>Items:</th>
<td><%= @order.order_items.sum(:quantity) %></td>
```

Comment: not working, the quantity is not added if I had the same product